Нужно ли импортировать defineProps и defineEmits?
Документация говорит: "Импортировать defineProps и defineEmits не нужно"
https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup#defineprops-defineemits
import { defineProps } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
    title: String,
});

так же мой код, который не работает без
import { defineProps } from "vue";

Подскажите, почему так?

defineProps и defineEmits — макросы компилятора используемые только внутри <script setup> . Их не нужно импортировать и они будут компилироваться при обработке <script setup>. defineProps принимает то же значение, что и опция props, а defineEmits принимает то же значение, что и опция emits.
